# Why is CloudFront ApiGateway CloudFront-Viewer-Country reporting US as the country for eu-west-1 distribution and viewer in UK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-api-gateway

I have an AWS CloudFront distribution created using CDK (`CloudFrontWebDistribution`) fronting an ApiGateway, deployed in `eu-west-1` (Dublin). I can see in the API logs that the `CloudFront-Viewer-Country` header is set to `US`, even though I am accessing the API from the UK.

Why is this please?